# Extend Symfony2 User object

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

In my data model I have two entities: "Companies" and "Clients". Companies represent companies I own and Clients are my clients. All Companies and Clients should have their own user account to login. Reading about Symfony2's security I created this model where Companies and Clients **extend** the [User object](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#security-crete-user-entity) that Symfony2 needs for Security.

My question is: will this work in the Symfony2 security framework with authentication and authorization? Also, is this the common way to model the data if you have multiple entities that map to a user?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work because the different authenticator out there use the "is instance of BaseUserClass" . And it seems quite logical to do the way you're doing.